# What have I done wrong to get ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python-3.x

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '> '

print ("Hi %s, I'm the %s script." % (user_name, script))
print ("I'd like to ask you a few questions.")
print ("Do you like me %s?" % user_name)
likes = input(prompt)

print ("Where do you live %s?" % user_name)
lives = input(prompt)

print ("What kind of computer do you have?")
computer = input(prompt)

print ("""
Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure wher that is.
And you have a %r computer. Nice.
""" % (likes, lives, computer))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the following line, the program is supposed to be passed 1 argument (except the program filename itself):

```
script, user_name = argv
```

You should launch the program with a username:

```
python script_file.py username
```